# Black screen when using a VGA monitor

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, vga

When I use a VGA monitor with my computer, the screen is black. I have tried Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 21.10 and Linux Mint 20.3. All have the same problem. It works perfectly fine with Windows.

If I use "Secure Boot", it works, but the graphics card uses a standard driver which doesn't really fit. (llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.1, 256 bits))

I have tried using the displayport output, and it works perfectly fine. I have also tried the install with both 3rd party programs and drivers and without. The graphics card I have is: AMD Radeon R7 Graphics.

If you need any additional information, please let me know.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: AMD Graphics should work with open-source drivers, automatically installed. Does it not work out-of-the-box or only after installing the proprietary overlay?

Comment: @ChanganAuto It does not work out of the box.

Comment: You say the monitor works with windows. Is that on the same computer with the same cable? If not try a different cable. I’ve had plenty of issues with VGA cables in the past

Comment: @PonJar Same computer, same cable, same monitor. So that's not the issue. But thanks for the help :)